# How to create a custom button in checkout. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Already I create button:
**Vendor_Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="custom-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- Add this item to configure your js file  -->
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Vendor/js/view/fee-checkout-form</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- And this to add your html template  -->
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Module_Vendor/fee-checkout-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**fee-checkout-form**

```
<button class="action apply primary" type="submit" value="Value">
                                    <span>Span</span>
                                </button>
```

**how I should create button,so that after clicking, the controller or model is called?**
ty for answer

Comment: did the button display in checkout page? You only need to call controller from the button click?

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML(Module_Vendor/fee-checkout-form), create a Button with click event,

```
<button type="button" class="action apply primary" value="Value" 
   data-bind="event: { 
       click:someFunction 
    }
/><span>Span</span>
</button>
```

Then in your js(Module_Vendor/js/view/fee-checkout-form) , You need to create a ajax function to call that controller,

```
define([
'uiComponent',
'jquery',
'ko',
], function(Component, $, ko) {
someFunction: function(data, event) {

    $('body').trigger('processStart');//Loader

    var Url = 'YourBaseUrl/routename/controllerpath/controllerfunc';    
        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                data:data
            }
        }).done(function (resp) {
            $('body').trigger('processStop');
            alert('success response');
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function                                           
    at UiClass.someFunction (gratuity-checkout-form.js:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (knockout.js:4255)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)` Error here ->  $('body')

Comment: after button click you are getting this error?

Comment: Yes, after button click

Comment: change "$" on "jQuery", now new error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded